# networkmanager / nmcli - possible to ignore connection.secondaries for a single connection?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, vpn, nmcli, connectivity

**TL;DR - If you have your ethernet connection defined with "connection.secondaries" in networkmanager / `nmcli` (to auto-connect to a vpn), is there a way to skip / ignore / override the secondary connection ONE time without removing it from the definition? e.g. like when your internet is out and you just want to connect to your lan and you'd like it to NOT auto-connect to vpn (and fail) for that ONE time...**

Background:

My internet went out today and I had ended up rebooting my pc for some changes completely unrelated to this... when it came back up, it failed to connect to my ethernet connection presumably bc I have a "secondary connection" defined so that it normally connects to vpn on startup.

Obviously, when my internet comes back up, it shouldn't be an issue. But in the meantime, I wanted to be able to ssh to another pc on my local network. ssh works fine normally and I didn't run into any problems until I rebooted... Both systems are running Fedora 35 if that matters.

Now I know that I *could* just remove the "connection.secondaries" definition, restore my ethernet connection (which would let me access my lan again), then re-add the definition again later. But... since Comcast are rather incompetent and this isn't the first time, I've had the issue... I was wondering is there a way to just temporarily connect while ignoring / overriding that one setting? e.g. so I that I might make an `nmcli` alias for it or something?

Comment: It's a matter of "routing". Look at `ip route`, read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: @waltinator i know basics but i'm not a network wiz. after looking through `man ip` / `man ip-route`, I get the impression that using `ip route` would be a permanent change, e.g. one that sticks around even after i reboot / my ISP comes back online, right? I was more hoping for something that could be used as a one-off without permanently modifying my configuration... If all else fails, I could also bang out functions to save/restore my config in nm but was hoping there was a more elegant way to approach the problem. apologies if you're referring something that is going over my head.